# How can I search photos by EXIF tags?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, windows-search, exif

I want to be able to find a specific photo in my huge archive, so I put some tags in the EXIF header.

The problem is: How can I search for a file that contains a specific tag (eg. "sky")?

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found one way in Windows 8:

In the search bar, enter `tags:yourtag`, in my example it would be `tags:sky`.

Comment: In Windows 10, it seems that you don't even need the `tags:` prefix.

Comment: this is how i'm searching: *.jpg tag:sky and it works (if the tags are written inside the jpg file)

Comment: Workds in Win10 für JPEG images, ignores raw Files (where the tags resides in .xmp sidecars.)

Comment: if you install nef codecs from nikon, you can write tags inside the nef files https://www.nikonimglib.com/nefcodec/

Answer (score 2):

I use totalcommander for most file related task. It has a very powerful search engine. One feature is that it can search for exif data. This feature is activated by installing a 'plugin' file from a number that are available. The program itself is a shareware and can be licensed at a very reasonable price. Really helpful for a lot of other tasks. I actually never use the 'file explorer' of windows.

Comment: i'm using TC from a long long time, but in explorer it is very simple, if I want to search the tag cat from a jpg file, all I have to do is to search for *.jpg tag:cat

Comment: but the plugin does not allow you to search by custom tags