# Add EXIF tags to NEF files

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, exif

I want to organize my photos. I know how to [search for EXIF tags from Windows Explorer](https://superuser.com/questions/543348/how-can-i-search-photos-by-exif-tags) but I don't know hot to add the tags in NEF files.

It looks like the input box is disabled. My question is: can the tags be added and if it can be done, does the search from Windows Explorer work?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, install the NEF RAW codec if you haven't already done so. Options include (in descending order of suitability):

1. [Direct from Nikon](http://www.nikonimglib.com/nefcodec/)
2. The [Microsoft Camera Codec Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26829) (Win8 update info [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2712101))
3. Non-free [FastPictureViewer Codec Pack](http://www.fastpictureviewer.com/codecs/nikon-nef-codec/)

Now check if Win Explorer allows you to add tags directly from the Properties dialog for NEF files. If not, there's always [ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) (tested adding tags to NEFs just now on Win7 x64) or even [Exiv2](http://www.exiv2.org). There's even an [ExifToolGUI](http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/~bogdan/) if you don't like command-line utilities:

[image: 1]

Comment: I've installed the codec from nikon and now I can add the tags from windows explorer. Also I want to mention that I've already installed Microsoft Camera Codec Pack and it only shows the thumbnails of nef files in windows 7/8. The nef codec was the only thing I needed. I had no idea there is such a codec. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, MS' codec pack is only to be tried if the camera manufacturer's codec is not available or fails to work properly. Only manufacturers know the full details about their proprietary RAW formats.

Answer (score 0):

ExifTool (http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) is a Perl library that claims to be able to do what you want, though I haven't tried using it.

Comment: i know about ExifTool, but I was looking for something easier to use, not a command line tool. I want to be able to add more tags to a group of files

Comment: Karan's answer is better; if that answer works I'll delete mine

Comment: @MarcusChan keep your answer. It could help someone else and it is actually an option.

Comment: Yes, but Karan mentioned this solution as an alternative

Comment: i wanted a solution that lets me add the tags from windows explorer and the nef codec did it for me... Thank you all for your hep