# How can I find a file (or group of files based off where they came from)?

Tags: search

I have some photos I pulled off a phone at an undetermined date.  I know it was in the past two years.  I am not sure where I stashed them.  Searching by date + filetype (kind:=picture), but this search took so long and didn't find what i was looking for (i think).  Is there a way to search filter on (from:= cellphone)?  I know that is unlikely but how can i filter this search better?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Windows and your file system is NTFS, you should use [everything](https://www.voidtools.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You could index the suspected locations with an EXIF aware application like Google Picasa (discontinued?) or Adobe Lightroom, then use the search feature to find images from a specific camera.

See this answer for a Windows 8 method that might work in other versions as well: [How can I search photos by EXIF tags?](https://superuser.com/questions/543348/how-can-i-search-photos-by-exif-tags)